# Как создать изображение в Python?

Tags: python, изображения

Представим, у меня есть набор пикселей. Не важно, как они расположены. Допустим, двумерный массив:

```
   [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Или как угодно. Не важно. В этом наборе пикселей указаны все пиксели, и допустим цифрой выбраны цвета. Как мне создать картинку, зная цвет каждого пикселя и его расположение? И необходимо чтобы можно было отрегулировать размер "пискеля". Допустим сама картинка размером 1200х1200 пикселей, но в ней 1 "пиксель" занимает 100 пикселей. В итоге там 12х12 "пикселей".

Comment: что-то вы намудрили с "подпиксилями".

Comment: бит, байт, 3 байта, 4 байта - как выбран  цвет?

Comment: @splash58 байт.

Comment: @splash58 извиняюсь, 4 бита - 16 цветов

Comment: Что значит создать картинку? Создать файл какого-то формата или Base64 строку для отправки браузеру?

Comment: @Leonid создать файл любого формата картинки

Comment: модуль pillow метод Image.new()

Comment: @Интик Image.new() позволяет создать просто цветной квадрат, а необходимо создать изображение из набора пикселей

Comment: ну так пробегите циклом по всем пикселям и перекрасьте как надо. время выполнения меньше секунды.

Comment: @Интик как перекрасить?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/451074/